# Resizable Pseudo elements based on Element size

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-selectors, pseudo-element

I currently have a feature in a webapp I am building which has a `span` with some inner text along with `:before` and `:after` psuedo elements which are simply used as a line on each side of the text.

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/scs29xad/) showing exactly what I mean.

```
.container{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 27px;
  margin-bottom: 18px;
  text-align: center;
}

.container .pseudos {
  font-size: 14px;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #999;
}

.container .pseudos:before, .container .pseudos:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30%;
  height: 1px;
  content: '';
  background-color: #999;
}

.container .pseudos:before {
  left: 0;
}

.container .pseudos:after {
  right: 0;
}
```

However if you drag the middle dragbar on the JSFiddle you will notice that the :before and :after elements will converge over the actual text which does not look very good.

Is there some CSS rules I could add which would make the `:before` and `:after` elements shrink themselves instead of converging over the text?

Or even a JS/Jquery solution?

Comment: An alternate solution can be like [**this**](https://jsfiddle.net/vivekkupadhyay/scs29xad/2) when your text has some kind of bg color viz merge-able to its container bg.

Comment: @vivekkupadhyay Ahh that's actually quite a nice solution and should work well for my project. Feel free to add it as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/line-on-sides-headers/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please have a look on this (a **Flex Box** solution)

```css
.container .pseudos::before, .container .pseudos::after { 
 height: 1px;
 content: '';
 background-color: #999;
 flex: 1;
 margin: 9px;
}
.container {
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 margin-top: 27px;
 margin-bottom: 18px; 
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<span class="pseudos" style="display: flex;flex-wrap: nowrap;width: 100%;"> My Very Long Piece Of Text Goes Here</span>
</div>
```

In this way the fixed width 30% is removed, and it is better for responsive.

Comment: I rearranged the answer and removed useless styles.

Answer (score 0):

A good workaround will be like when you put your text inside any tag and assign a `background-color` to that tag similar to the `background-color` of its parent or container then you can resize your window/container to get the desired effect.

### Code Snippet

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 27px;
  margin-bottom: 18px;
  text-align: center;
}

.container .pseudos {
  font-size: 14px;
  display: block;
  color: #999;
  position: relative;
}

.container .pseudos span {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #ffffff;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  position: relative;
}

.container .pseudos:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 13px;
  left: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: #999;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span class="pseudos"><span>My Very Long Piece Of Text Goes Here</span></span>
</div>
```

<kbd>[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/vivekkupadhyay/scs29xad/3/)</kbd>